# Cassandra 3.2.1 cluster using lots of bandwidth

Tags: cassandra

Not even sure where to start looking for the answer to this one.

I have four t2.micro nodes running an almost idle Cassandra cluster for testing. Two nodes are in one DC and two nodes in another. I am using EC2 snitch and everything seems to be working.

```
Datacenter: us-east
===================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host     ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.160  89.35 MB   256          51.3%             62ed3b67-aaa0-4ada-bcfc-240559ee25d5  1e
UN  192.168.1.161  35.09 MB   256          48.7%             ea485c5a-10a2-42fc-8e97-67b164cd7e5d  1e
UN  192.168.2.195  65.39 MB   256          48.4%             3697ef93-8312-4783-8112-38959690c005  1a
UN  192.168.2.196  59.97 MB   256          51.6%             7ae1e1d3-1e4b-4f45-809c-863c786f48af  1a
```

I have a very small table that has been getting about 10-20 writes a second.

What blows my mind is that this little cluster is doing about 10-30GB of data transfer a day. Something is wrong and I am such a Cassandra noob that I have no idea where to even start. I wiped the cluster and there was a small dip, but it quickly went back. I want to understand what this usage is and how it scales with load.

Here is the CloudWatch graph:
[image]

Here is a copy/paste of my config, which I believe to be "mostly" stock (comments removed to make it a suitable length):

```
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
num_tokens: 256
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000
max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128
batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
role_manager: CassandraRoleManager
roles_validity_in_ms: 2000
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
disk_failure_policy: stop
commit_failure_policy: stop
key_cache_size_in_mb:
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
counter_cache_size_in_mb:
counter_cache_save_period: 7200
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "192.168.1.161, 192.168.2.196"
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32
concurrent_materialized_view_writes: 32
memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_interface: eth0
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: false
rpc_interface: eth0
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5
batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100
sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
cross_node_timeout: false
endpoint_snitch: Ec2Snitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    optional: false
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
internode_compression: all
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
tracetype_query_ttl: 86400
tracetype_repair_ttl: 604800
gc_warn_threshold_in_ms: 1000
enable_user_defined_functions: false
enable_scripted_user_defined_functions: false
windows_timer_interval: 1
```

Here is a copy of my keyspace:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE stuff WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'us-east': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

Comment: Don't you read nothing from this cluster ?

Comment: No. I isolated it and left it idle in a test cluster while I try to figure out why the bandwidth usage is so high. A daemon inserts 10-20 rows a second. These rows are very small.